# How many permutations of {1,2,..., 9} are there that do not start or end with an even number?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

How many permutations of $$1,2,..., 9$$ are there that do not start or end with an even number?

This is my attempt

Condition 1 [Starts with even] => $$4 * 8!$$
Condition 2 [Ends with even] => $$4 * 8! $$
Condition 3 [Starts with even and Ends with even] => $$4*3*7!$$

Therefore, $$9! - (Condition1 +Condition2 -Condition 3)$$

Is this the right answer?

Comment: Sounds right, except you swapped two signs in the last formula. **Edit:** Or else you meant a parenthesis, as in $9! - ( \text{Condition 1} + \text{Condition 2} - \text{Condition 3} )$.

Comment: You seem to have correctly calculated the number of ways to start and end with an even number.  Surely a similar strategy works for odd numbers and is simpler than the inclusion-exclusion you have here.

Comment: I think people are getting confused with AND and OR here. This would be the solution for "OR" not "AND" From what I know this would be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**:  This answer pertains to the original version of the question, which did not have parentheses in the final displayed equation. **end note**

Your approach would be OK if you wrote it as

$$9!-Condition1-Condition2+Condition3$$

That would be using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle:  Start with the unrestricted number ($9!$), subtract off the numbers that violate the two conditions, but then realize you've subtracted *twice* the ones that violate both conditions.

But another way to solve the problem directly is to put *odd* numbers at the beginning and end, in $5\cdot4$ ways, and then fill in the rest in $7!$ ways.

Comment: Fixed the sign. Thanks :) Not used to latex

Answer (score 4):

Pick the first digit: ${5 \choose 1}$.  Pick the last digit: ${4 \choose 1}$.  Place the rest of them: $7!$.

That gives $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 7! = 100800$ possibilities.

Comment: Wouldn't that only give the possibilities that start AND end with even number? The question is start with, or end with. What you wrote is exactly what I had for condition 3.

Comment: There is only 4 even numbers 1 to 9

Comment: I wrote it correctly the first time, saw Eric's answer, and thought I got it backwards. Turns out *he* got it backwards. :)  I switched it back to my original answer.

Comment: Isn't it that it *doesn't* start or end with an even digit?  Meaning, it must start *and* end with an odd digit?

Comment: Starts with odd and ends with even counts. Starts with even and ends with odd counts. Starts with even and odd counts. So if you just count for when it starts AND end withs odd, I believe this is undercounting? But this gives the same answer. I believe I have a misconception going on here.

Comment: The English phrase "that do not start or end with an even number" means "that neither starts nor ends with an even number".  You seem to want "that do not start with an even number or do not end with an even number", which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Five choices for first digit.  Four remaining choices for last digit.  Arbitrary order of the remaining 7 digits in between.

$5 \times 7! \times 4 = 100800$

Your (updated) method gives 100800.  So we seem to agree.

Edited to reverse the transposition of "even" and "odd" in my solution.

Edited to incorporate edits to the problem's final formula.

Comment: It's $5$ and $4$, not $4$ and $3$.  The first and last digit need to be odd.

Comment: Correct result is then $100{\,}800$.

Comment: @John:  You're right.  Solution fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As John pointed out, there's an easier approach to this, but you're nevertheless on the right track to a solution using inclusion-exclusion; you just missed a sign in your formula! If $B$ and $E$ are the sets of permutations beginning and ending with even numbers (respectively), then you want to compute $|B^c\cap E^c|$ where $S^c = S_9 - S$ denotes the complement of $S$ in the set $S_9$ of permutations on $1,\ldots,9$. So by inclusion exclusion and de Morgan's law

$$
|B^c\cap E^c| = |S_9 \setminus (B \cup E)| = 9! - (|B| + |E| - |B\cap E|) = 9! - |B| - |E| + |B\cap E|
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct. It says

$$9! - (4 \cdot 8! + 4 \cdot 8! - 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 7!)$$

which calculates to

$$9! - 4 \cdot 7! \cdot (8 + 8 - 3) = 9! - 4 \cdot 7! \cdot 13 = (9 \cdot 8 - 4 \cdot 13) \cdot 7! = 20 \cdot 7!$$

Now other people's answers show another (simpler) way to see that the answer is $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 7!$.